# Why does Cycles render Weird even w very low subsurface scattering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, subsurface-scattering

The cycles renders completely different from Eevee even with a very low subsurface scattering of 0.06. Or is 0.06 too high for plants? If i set it to zero it's fine but should it not have some value?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cycles and Eevee us very different approaches. Cycles simulates light while Eevee is more of an approximation.
This looks like render noise to me, so I'd say it probably is too much SS. Also I don't think the stem of the plant would have much SS to begin with.

Comment: The value is in units, and can be translated to meters, so 0.06 is 6 cm. If your subsurface radius is around 1 m, it means the light will scatter under the skin of your objects for roughly 6 cm (This isn't how it works under the hood but I think it's close to what actually happens). So if your stem is less than 6 cm wide, light has a chance of completely traversing it without being reflected back. Hence the fruit jelly look. So either you lower the subsurface radius vector or you have to use a very low subsurface value

Comment: You have a procedural texture directly connected to a normal socket. You can't expect any type of coherent results with a setup like that

Comment: I second @DuarteFarrajotaRamos opinion, try removing the Normal input on your Principled shader, bet money that will fix it.

Comment: @Gorgious hey you are right! my plant does start growing from 6cm until it's huge 12m tall full fledged tree. so i probably need to animate the subsurface scattering value from 0 to a certain bigger value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because subsurface scattering is greatly dependent on the actual scale of the object, bigger objects will require higher values to have the same amount of SSS while small objects need smaller values. You also need to have a [bump](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/bump.html) node between the procedural texture and the normal channel.